# Почему не работает DeflaterInputStream

Tags: java, deflate

Почему не работают функции:

```
    public static byte[] deflateComp(String data) throws Exception{
    if (data == null || data.length() == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream obj = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DeflaterOutputStream gzip = new DeflaterOutputStream(obj);
    gzip.write(data.getBytes());
    gzip.close();
    return obj.toByteArray();
}

    public static byte[] deflateDec(byte[] str) throws Exception {
    if (str == null) {
        return null;
    }
    DeflaterInputStream gis = new DeflaterInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(str));
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gis));

    return bf.readLine().getBytes();
}
```

Делаю что-то типо этого

```
        Voider.log("SSS", newString(Compressor.deflateDec(Compressor.deflateComp("TTT"))));
```

На выходе получаю

```
        [Name:SSS] [Value:x�����������/��-,]
```

Comment: Видать с кодировкой чего-то.

Comment: Я кодировку не трогаю и не меняю, там utf-8